# Settings file in android application

Tags: java, android

At first, I need an advice how to store private settings in Android application. This settings will contain server/login/password/clientId which are required by application to log into REST API. Settings could be changed in the future, so I need solution which can "easly" update it on all devices - app will be used on +700 client phones. Phones does not have SD Card.

My concept is to store this settings in a hashed text file. I can send prepared setting file to Client, then Client copy it to device memory via USB to the given location - new folder in the main storage where Alarms, DCIM etc are.

Is this a good solution ?

Example methods to check storage - on my test phone both returning false:

```
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
      String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

How to save file in android external memory (not SD Card) ?

Comment: why don't you use a central server for this and make request to the server first time the user logs in and store the settings locally then. that way when you have to change settings you can just change them on server and it'll be updated on all devices instead of sending settings files to 700+ devices

Answer (score 0):

Great doc here :
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Please read it to understand that the external storage does not mean SD card for android. And that even a phone without sd card will have a external storage

You need this permission in your manifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

(for me the read permission works as well...)

Then for newer android versions you need to ask the permission

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RIGHT_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

Then I use getExternalFilesDir to get my application directory to store some files.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

But since you don't want removeable storage you may be better off with getFilesDir https ://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

PS: I just noticed the doc says you don't need any permission to access your application directory since KitKat. May take a look at that later...